# How to use Join, GroupBy and Average on C# Objects using LINQ

Tags: linq

I would like to join two objects and group them into one and perform a average query using LINQ. The following are my classes

```
public class emp
  {
     public int empID { get; set; }
     public string empName { get; set; }
  }
public class salaries
  {
     public int empID { get; set; }
     public string month { get; set; }
     public int salary { get; set; }
   }

public void repository()
        {
            lstemp = new List<emp> { 
            new emp{empID=1,empName="A"},
            new emp{empID=2,empName="B"},
            new emp{empID=3,empName="C"}
            };

            lstsalary = new List<salaries> { 
            new salaries{empID=1,month="jan",salary=1000},
            new salaries{empID=1,month="feb",salary=1500},
            new salaries{empID=1,month="mar",salary=2000},

              new salaries{empID=2,month="jan",salary=1500},
            new salaries{empID=2,month="feb",salary=2000},

              new salaries{empID=3,month="jan",salary=1500},
            new salaries{empID=3,month="feb",salary=2000},
            new salaries{empID=3,month="mar",salary=2000},
            new salaries{empID=3,month="apr",salary=2000},
            };
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            new calculator().repository();
            var result = from e in calculator.lstemp
                         join
                             s in calculator.lstsalary on e.empID equals s.empID 
                             group s by s.empID into grp
                         select new {

                             salary = (from g in grp where g.empID == grp.Key select g.salary).Average()
                         };            
        }
```

Now from the above data i want to group according to the empID and then i would like to take an average from thier respective salary.

> The result should be having the empName and the average salary of the
>   employee.

How can in achieve this.
Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to learn about and start following the .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store both objects in an anonymous type, to access the empName you could also  group by both properties, the id and the name:

```
var result = from e in calculator.lstemp
     join s in calculator.lstsalary on e.empID equals s.empID 
     let empSal = new { emp = e, sal = s }
     group empSal by new { empSal.emp.empID, empSal.emp.empName } into g
     select new
     {
         empName = g.Key.empName,
         salary = g.Average(x => x.sal.salary)
     };
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i just wanted to make sure is this the right way or is there any other way where we can boost the performance of the query. I just wanted to learn various ways of query and techniques.Thank you